# Retrieve dictionary items inside a list ? python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new and self teaching myself python. I've been researching for a day now on how to do the below and need guidance please.

I'm trying to retrieve the values for minutes, hours, seconds etc from this, but i believe its a dictionary wrapped in a list ?? so that confuses me

```
[Slot(slotName='Duration', entity='snips/duration', rawValue='for 3 minutes', value={'kind': 'Duration', 'years': 0, 'quarters': 0, 'months': 0, 'weeks': 0, 'days': 0, 'hours': 0, 'minutes': 3, 'seconds': 0, 'precision': 'Exact'}, range={'start': 13, 'end': 26}, alternatives=[], confidenceScore=None)]
```

The code snippet i have is below :

```
        if 'Duration' in session.slotsAsObjects:
            print("running duration code")
            print("")

            slotObjects = session.slotsAsObjects

            print("slotObjects type is ", type(slotObjects))
            print("")
            print("slotObjects returns : ", slotObjects)
            print(slotObjects.get('Duration'))
            print("")

            slot = slotObjects.get('Duration', list())

            print("slot type is :", type(slot))
            print("")
            print("Slot value is ", slot)
            print("")

            if slot:
                minutes = slot[0]
                print("Below is what print(slot[0]) returns ")
                print(minutes)

            else:
                print("nothing to see here ")
```

and the output of the above is below:

```
running duration code

slotObjects type is  <class 'collections.defaultdict'>

slotObjects returns :  defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'AddReminder': [Slot(slotName='AddReminder', entity='AddReminder', rawValue='reminder', value={'kind': 'Custom', 'value': 'reminder'}, range={'start': 4, 'end': 12}, alternatives=[], confidenceScore=None)], 'Duration': [Slot(slotName='Duration', entity='snips/duration', rawValue='for 3 minutes', value={'kind': 'Duration', 'years': 0, 'quarters': 0, 'months': 0, 'weeks': 0, 'days': 0, 'hours': 0, 'minutes': 3, 'seconds': 0, 'precision': 'Exact'}, range={'start': 13, 'end': 26}, alternatives=[], confidenceScore=None)]})
[Slot(slotName='Duration', entity='snips/duration', rawValue='for 3 minutes', value={'kind': 'Duration', 'years': 0, 'quarters': 0, 'months': 0, 'weeks': 0, 'days': 0, 'hours': 0, 'minutes': 3, 'seconds': 0, 'precision': 'Exact'}, range={'start': 13, 'end': 26}, alternatives=[], confidenceScore=None)]

slot type is : <class 'list'>

Slot value is  [Slot(slotName='Duration', entity='snips/duration', rawValue='for 3 minutes', value={'kind': 'Duration', 'years': 0, 'quarters': 0, 'months': 0, 'weeks': 0, 'days': 0, 'hours': 0, 'minutes': 3, 'seconds': 0, 'precision': 'Exact'}, range={'start': 13, 'end': 26}, alternatives=[], confidenceScore=None)]

Below is what print(slot[0]) returns 
Slot(slotName='Duration', entity='snips/duration', rawValue='for 3 minutes', value={'kind': 'Duration', 'years': 0, 'quarters': 0, 'months': 0, 'weeks': 0, 'days': 0, 'hours': 0, 'minutes': 3, 'seconds': 0, 'precision': 'Exact'}, range={'start': 13, 'end': 26}, alternatives=[], confidenceScore=None)
```

Appreciate any guidance on this

Comment: What is this `session` and `Slot` class? The `Slot` class should have some method to let you access its data. Try printing `dir(slot[0])`

Comment: Result of dir(slot[0]) is :  ['__annotations__', '__class__', '__dataclass_fields__', '__dataclass_params__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'alternatives', 'confidenceScore', 'entity', 'range', 'rawValue', 'slotName', 'value']

Comment: So not fully sure what that outcome means but at first glance would that indicate that 'value' should be able to be extracted so i can get access to the keys  ?

Comment: Yes, very likely. You could possibly use the "kind" in the dictionary returned by `slot[0].value()` (if that is what it returns) to determine the type and then check for other fields.

Answer (score 0):

i've come across the answer i'm after thanks.

```
@staticmethod
  def getDuration(session: DialogSession) -> int:
    slots = session.slotsAsObjects
    duration = 0
    if 'Duration' in slots and slots['Duration'][0].entity == 'snips/duration':
      with suppress(TypeError, KeyError):
        values = slots['Duration'][0].value
        duration += values['seconds']
        duration += values['minutes'] * 60
        duration += values['hours'] * 60 * 60
        duration += values['days'] * 24 * 60 * 60
        duration += values['weeks'] * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
        duration += values['months'] * 4 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60

    return duration
```